# Javascript writing HTML to page error

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have read all SO posts on 'Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list' and none of them solve this problem. I don't understand what is wrong.

I am returning JSON for a database and writing HTML for each result.

```
function addRow(str, count) {
str = str.substr(0, str.length -5);
document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML += '<br /><br /><div  
class="input-group"><span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-success" 
onclick="javascript:del(' + "'" + str + "'" + ');" type="button">Delete</button></span><p class="form-control">'+str+'</p><span class="input-group-btn"><button onclick="javascript:publish('+str+');" class="btn btn-success" type="button">Publish</button>
</span></div>';
}
```

This is the code that creates the HTML.

I do not get an error until I click the 'publish button'. So I'd assume something is wrong with this code or the publish function.

```
function publish(text) {
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://example.com/test.php?type=upcom&text="+text,true);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("comments").innerHTML = "";
            loadComment();
        }
    }
}
```

Above is the publish method.

Can anybody spot anything that would cause 'Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list'?

Ive spent hours on this problem.

Thanks

Comment: Where do you see this "Uncaught SyntaxError"? in the "comments" element?

Comment: It throws it for line 2, the html tag

Comment: Is that your actual code? You can't have line breaks inside strings.

Comment: The html is written as a string them appended to a dav based on the JSON result

Comment: What happen if you just type the request in the some browser tab url? http://example.com/test.php?type=upcom&text="+text (your real text goes here instead of text variable)

Comment: The JSON returns correctly. Yesterday when i was just just one button it was actually working for a short time. Adding the delete button in the same manner threw it off. In the code str is a comment coming back from json and the appended HTML displays great. But on clicking the button i get the error

Comment: you are putting the xmlhttp object in global scope. any concurrent request will make it fail. Add a `var` to make it local.

Comment: You have spaces in your del javascript:
javascript:del(' + "'" + str + "'" + ');" shoud be:
javascript:del('+"'" + str + "'"+');"

And can you tell me what you're using the double quotes for?

Comment: @kizeloo Thank you, this was the root of the syntax error. You solved a very hard problem for me! I have accepted the below answer as I could not accept your comment and you both point to the root. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think here is the problem, there is not quotes:

```
<button onclick="javascript:publish('+str+');">
```

So if **str** is "my comments", will generate an error:

```
<button onclick="javascript:publish(my comments);">
```

## To solve use like this:

```
<button onclick="javascript:publish(\''+str.replace(/\'/g,'\\'') +'\')
```

So if **str** is "my comments", will generate:

```
<button onclick="javascript:publish('my comments');">
```

So if **str** is "calmcalmuncle's comments", will generate:

```
<button onclick="javascript:publish('calmcalmuncle\'s comments');">
```

## Edit:

You need to fix this too:

```
<button onclick="javascript:del(' + "'" + str + "'" + ');">Delete</button>
```

Same way:

```
<button onclick="javascript:del(\''+str.replace(/\'/g,'\\'');">Delete</button>
```

Comment: Thank you, it was indeed a problem with the spaces. you saved me a lot of time!